# Understanding particular date/time format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the use of the following format, supported by Moment.js?

```
> const moment=require('moment')
undefined
> moment().format('h AM/PM')
'3 PM10/P10'
```

Particularly, what does `PM10/P10` mean? From the docs [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/:%7E:text=1971%20...%202029%202030-,AM/PM,am%20pm,-Hour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's parsing the string through its constituent pieces of the date time spec: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

However the wiki it's tricky to understand, so to breakdown what its returning:

The string `h AM/PM` breakdown as:

- `h` (no zero) Hour
- `A` AM / PM postfix
- `M` Month
- `/P` a text slash and letter P
- `M` Month

Therefore splitting on the output string: `3 PM10/P10` looks like this:

```
h A  M  /P M
3 PM 10 /P 10
```

---

That said, you probably only want the `h A` as your format string - this cheat-sheet should help: https://devhints.io/moment

```
> const moment=require('moment')
undefined
> moment().format('h A')
'3 PM'
```

Comment: Oh, got it. `M` is month not part of the `AM` specification.